# How can I update multiple records in one query

Tags: laravel, query-builder

my table Inventory column
`[id qty price]`
 my want update

```
$items = [{ id:1, qty:5 }, { id:7, qty:3 }, { id:2, qty:4 }]
```

like
`update(items)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can't

It is possible to **create** multiple records this way, using `insert`, but there is no equivalent for updating. Instead you'll have to loop through your items and update them individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert multiple records in one time.  $trainer->Update() for update;

Your Blade:

```
<select name="subunit[]" id="submit" class="select2" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="">Select Option</option>
    </select>
```

Your controller:

Add this top of controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

function:

public function valueStore(Request $request)
     {
          $input = Input::all();
            for ($idx = 0; $idx < count(Input::get('subunit')); $idx++)
            {
              $trainer = new AssignTrainer();
              $trainer->course_id = $request['course_id'];
              $trainer->subunit_id =  $request['subunit'][$idx];
              $trainer->save();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Elonquent, you can do this in you controller:

```
foreach ($items as $object) {
   Inventory::where('id', '=', $object.id)
            ->update(['qty' => $object.qty]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eloquent:

for example, updating Country in businesses table:

```
App\Business::whereIn('id',[id1,id2,id3,id4])->update(['country'=>'Kenya']);
```